# Will my code safely check for an underflow?

Tags: c++

I wrote the following C++ code to check for an underflow. Not sure this is a good practice or not.

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float d = 1.e-29;
    std::cout<<"d: "<<d<<" underflow? "<<(d<std::numeric_limits<float>::min())<<std::endl;
    d = 1.e-59;
    std::cout<<"d: "<<d<<" underflow? "<<(d<std::numeric_limits<float>::min())<<std::endl;
}
```

The printouts are

```
d: 1e-29 underflow? 0
d: 0 underflow? 1
```

Comment: just thinking logically, this would, by definition, **fail** to detect any underflow.

Comment: Logically speaking, how could any ``float`` ever be less than ``std::numeric_limits<float>::min()``? That's a contradiction.

Comment: @user3477950 why was it?

Comment: @HailiangZhang How could any `float` be less than the _minimum float value_?

Comment: The code looks OK to me. min() is the minimum positive value, so 0.0f is < to min().

Comment: @Rémi: It's quite obviously not okay. You physically can't detect an underflow/overflow _after_ it's occurred, like this. It doesn't matter what `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` returns you.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot check for underflow or overflow *after* a variable has been assigned a value by comparing it with the standard limits.

Simple example:

```
int v1 = INT_MAX;
int v2 = INT_MAX;
int v3 = v1 * v2;
```

The expression `v1 * v2` results in an overflow. However the value of `v3` will still be a valid `int`.

You have to performs checks prior to `v1 * v2` to determine whether it will result in an overflow.

Comment: This is true for integers, but float underflow should be testable on the result.

Comment: "the value of v3 will still be a valid int." - no, because the overflow invoked undefined behavior. it may be anything (including a trap representation).